# Does C++ STL or TR1(not boost::tr1) work only on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, visual-c++-2010, tr1

I was thinking STL was a standard implementation, though TR1 may not be. But does the platform matter? I was thinking it would work on Windows/Linux/Unix/Mac. I have people saying it wont work on anything other than Windows.

Please let me know.

-TIA

Comment: Peoble tell you nonsense or you didn't get right what they were saying.

Comment: Both STL and TR1 are library *specifications*, respectively from 1994 and 2005. They're not implementations. Anyone can implement anything they like for any platform. Why are we talking about this ancient, dead stuff though? The C++ standard library contains many useful aspects of both the STL and the TR1, and actual, usable implementations ship with all contemporary C++ compilers.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#History) ( not to be confused with the C++ standard library ) was developed by Alexander Stepanov when working for HP and Silicon Graphics. Much of the STL later was included into the C++ standard library, hence sometimes the STL and the templated containers in the C++ standard library are confused.

The second STL implementation (SGI) was designed to work with any standard complient C++ compiler, though IIRC not the early Microsoft 'C++' compilers due to lack of required features. (I seem to recall trying to play with it in the late 90s). The C++ standard library now requires some [compiler intrinsics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) so there is no 'standard implementation' possible. (IIRC these are for atomic operations, but edit or comment if you know better)

So the implementation of the C++ standard library which ships with Visual Studio will only work with 'Windows'*, and probably only with Microsoft's C++ compiler. Other implementations will work with other compilers and on other platforms.

*Visual studio C++ can cross compile to other variants of Windows, so a version of the standard library for Windows 10 x64 will not work on Windows 7 ARM embedded.

Comment: Can you give an example to a STL usage that requires the compiler to use an intristic function? I'm sure there are, I just can't come up with one.

Comment: @user3104201 Other than the one above, no.

Comment: You can implement atomic operations using mutexes (very inefficiently). std::is_pod is not possible to accurately implement without compiler support (it is safe to assume that e.g. no type is a POD, but it's again inefficient.).

Comment: @n.m. - you're right that you can implement atomic operations using mutexes, but an important goal of atomics is to be lock-free, and an implementation with mutexes is not lock-free. So an implementation with mutexes is formally conforming, but useless in practice.